# Number of $\{0,1\}$ vectors with given runs

Tags: combinatorics, coding-theory

What is number of $\{0,1\}^n$ vectors which have $01$ patterns at exactly $k$ coordinates?

Comment: This isn't clear, at least not to me.  Can you work it out explicitly for $n≤3$, say?

Comment: @lulu $010001001001$ has exactly $01$ at four coordinates. I think the order is around $(n/k)^k$.

Comment: In that example, what is $n$?  Surely you can answer your question exactly for small $n$, no?

Comment: @lulu $n=4$ and $k=2$ we have $0101$. Number $=1$.

Comment: Not sure why you are reluctant to answer my question precisely.  Are you saying that $F(4,2)=1$?  So, $F(4,1)$ would be $11$ ?  Here, of course, $F(n,k)$ denotes the number you are seeking.

Comment: @lulu $0100$,$0010$,$0001$,$0110$, $0011$,$0111$, $1010$,$1011$, $1001$, $1101$.

Comment: $F(3,1)$ would be $4$ since we have $010,011,101,001$ as the only "good strings", yes?

Comment: What's wrong with $1011$, say?  Sorry...too hard to get information here.   I don't think I am helping.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if we start with $0$ then this corresponds to seperating the places into $2k$ or $2k+1$ non empty chunks ( the chunks of consecutive coordinates that are all the same), which by stars and bars can be done in $\binom{n-1}{2k-1}+\binom{n-1}{2k}$ ways.

if we start with $1$ then we have to separate into $2k+1$ or $2k+2$ chunks and we get $\binom{n-1}{2k}+\binom{n-1}{2k+1}$

Comment: I think that last summand should be $\binom{n-1}{2k+1}$

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot !

Comment: Huh, when you add those all up and use Pascal's identity, you get $\binom{n+1}{2k+1}$. I wonder if there is a more direct proof...

Comment: There is, but it is not so interesting. String of length $n$ with $k$ $01$'s are in bijection with strings of length $n+2$, starting with $1$ and ending with $0$, which have exactly $2k+1$ instances of either $01$ or $10$.